# collections and eloquent results

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I have a set of row returned from a function and stored in a variable called $topics. Each topic contains a set of articles. so for the variable $topics if we do $topics[0]->articles we get several articles, and if we do $topics[1]->articles we get another set of articles. What i want to do is to put all these articles in one variable lets call it $articles so that I can do operations such as 
$articles->where('author', 'Jone Doe')->get();

I tried to do this:

```
$articles =  new collection();
foreach( $topics as $topic) {
  foreach( $topic->articles as $article)
      $articles->push($article);
```

But this unfortunately destroys the actual structure of the articles. like I can't do $articles->translations where i use a translation package. but i can do $topics[0]->articles->translations. basically i want to get all the articles in one collection as if they were returned from doing something like

```
$articles = Article::all()->get();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `pluck` method on your collection

```php
$articles = $topics->pluck('articles');
```

And if you wish a 1-dimension articles collection

```php
$articles = $topics->flatMap(function ($topic) {
    return $topic->articles;
});
```